# How can a Jade template use client-side global variables?

Tags: javascript, pug

Lets say I have a browser open, and in JavaScript I declare a global variable.

```
window.myGlobalVar = 'Hello!';
```

I then compile a jade template for client side rendering that uses that variable.

```
.foo= myGobalVar
```

Which I compile like so:

```
jade.compile('.foo= myGobalVar', {
  client: true,
  compileDebug: false
}).toString()
```

Which yields this template function:

```
function anonymous(locals) {
    var buf = [];
    var locals_ = (locals || {}),
        myGobalVar = locals_.myGobalVar;
    jade.indent = [];
    buf.push("\n<div class=\"foo\">"
             + (jade.escape(null == (jade.interp = myGobalVar) ? "" : jade.interp))
             + "</div>");;
    return buf.join("");
}
```

Which when ran, would produce:

```
<div class="foo">undefined</div>
```

---

As you can see, the jade compiler notices that I used a variable, and forces it to be a local variable via `myGobalVar = locals_.myGobalVar;`, which shadows the global variable I actually want to use.

So I tried referencing `window.myGlobalVar` and jade then just shadowed `window`.

Why not just pass in every global I want to use? Well at runtime I'm not sure what globals are necessary.  I have dozens of global constructors and passing them all in explicitly will require quite the refactoring.

So how do I get a client side jade template compiled in a way that allows references to glbal varaibles?

---

Update:

I did sort of succeed with this.

```
for (key in window) {
  if (localsObject[key] == null)
    localsObject[key] = window[key];
  }
}

renderTemplate(localsObject);
```

But god damn does that make me feel dirty... Surely there is a better way?

Comment: (just bringing attention to `myGobalVar` vs `myGlobalVar`)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the names of the globals, you want to use in jade templates, with the options object to the compile function. See jade api docs: http://jade-lang.com/api/

```
jade.compile(template, { globals: ['globalone','globaltwo']})
```

See this fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/lchngr/J5WJb/5/

Comment: your fiddle does not have the jade file

Comment: there is no jade file! the jade code is the string. please have a look at the fiddle again and rethink your down vote. but the link to imported momentjs lib was broken. I updated the fiddler link