# PUG/JADE option object in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, pug

I have a task for pug in a gulpfile.js that is something like this:

```
gulp.task('pug', function () {
return gulp.src('bundle/pages/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
        pretty:true,
        globals: ???,
        e.t.c.????????????????????
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('bundle/pages/'))

})
```

In pug docs we can see many options, but usually people use only "pretty:true". In docs I saw some interesting options like "globals" e.t.c

I want to include a global mixins file to all pug files without writing this inclusion in every .pug file like: "include ../../blah-blah/blah/global-mixins.pug:" at the top.

Is it possible to connect global-mixins.pug or another pug file using a pug pipe in gulpfile.js or not???

And where i can see an example of using all of the pug options in gulpfile.js, not just "pretty:true"???
https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537049/how-can-a-jade-template-use-client-side-global-variables (pug is renamed jade)